# Iterar en un DataFrame y plotear

Tags: python

En Python sobre **spyder**, tengo una **DataFrame** con datos de lluvias diarias, al cual lo agrupe por mes(suma de lluvias diarias). Quiero ahora graficar esos totales de lluvias, que salga cada estación con su gráfica de barras por mes.

```
datos=pd.read_csv('g1pp_19.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

df=pd.DataFrame(datos)
```

Aquí agrupo por mes:

```
dat_mes = datos.groupby(lambda m:m.month)
mes = datos.resample('M').sum()
```

A una variable `x` le asigno la longitud de las columnas del **DataFrame**

```
x = len(df.columns)
```

Para iterar y graficar:

```
i = 0
for col in x:
 grafica = mes[col].plot(subplots=True,figsize=(12,8), kind='bar')
 plt.title(mes.columns[i], weigth='bold', size=14)
 i=i+1
```

Cuando hago Run sale el mensaje de:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: x es un literal, no un iterable por lo que no puedes hacer un for sobre él porque aunque el valor fuera de 1000 sigue siendo solo un numero, no una variable con 1000 posiciones. Prueba a iterar sobre range(x) que eso sí devuelve un iterable con "x" posiciones (`for col in range(x)`)

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo: inclui el _range(x)_, y sale ahora el error de **KeyError:0**

Comment: Pon el mensaje de error completo. Revisando el codigo veo que estas incrementando un indice de una manera que no es propia de Python. Quita el `i = 0` y el `i = i + 1` y cambia el for por `for i, col in enumerate(range(x)):` El modulo `enumerate()` te devuelve las veces que lo loopeas. Aunque tambien podrias dejar de usar completamente la variable i y usar col tambien puesto que ambos numeros deberian ser iguales cada vuelta

Comment: Sigo leyendo tu código más en detalle y no entiendo bien como haces para mostrar la grafica. Puedes modificar tu pregunta y poner todo el codigo completo?

Comment: ok gracias, realice la modificación sugerida por vos, y sale: _File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item_ **KeyError:**0

Comment: con respecto a la gráfica no hace nada

Comment: Te complicas sin razón, en vez de iterar usar indizado numérico, usa las etiquetas: `for col in df.columns:` luego  `grafica = mes[col]...)` y `plt.title(colum, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Al asignar la longitud de `df.columns` a `x` esta contiene un entero. Los enteros no son iterables en python y de ahí tu error. Para solucionarlo usa directamente el `pandas.DataDrame` así:

```
for c in df:
    process_column(c)
```